# Could not resolve project :react-native-camera. on Android

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-camera

I am building using EAS but when i build im getting this error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve project :react-native-camera. 

     Required by:
project :app

      > The consumer was configured to find an API of a component, preferably optimized for Android, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'debug', attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr' with value '7.4.1'. However we cannot choose between the following variants of project :react-native-camera:
          - generalDebugApiElements
          - mlkitDebugApiElements
        All of them match the consumer attributes:
          - Variant 'generalDebugApiElements' capability APP_NAME:react-native-camera:unspecified declares an API of a component, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr' with value '7.4.1', attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'debug':
              - Unmatched attributes:
                  - Provides attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.ProductFlavor:react-native-camera' with value 'general' but the consumer didn't ask for it

                  - Provides attribute 'com.android.build.gradle.internal.attributes.VariantAttr' with value 'generalDebug' but the consumer didn't ask for it

                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for Android)

                  - Provides attribute 'react-native-camera' with value 'general' but the consumer didn't ask for it

          - Variant 'mlkitDebugApiElements' capability APP_NAME:react-native-camera:unspecified declares an API of a component, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr' with value '7.4.1', attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'debug':
```

I tried to do this solution but im still getting the error:

https://github.com/react-native-camera/react-native-camera/issues/2150#issuecomment-476011915